# independent variables implies integrability and same distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I want to solve this difficult problem, so I need your help,

I want to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent real variables such that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent, then $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are integrable and $X-E(X)$ and $Y-E(Y)$ are identically distributed .

I don't know exactly how to begin.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: this is not true

Comment: yes you're wright

Comment: Just take $X$ and $Y$ to be distinct constants for a counterexample.

Comment: I corrected it, I think it is true now

Comment: it is a problem about a characterisation of normal distribution, the first question is as above, the second is to deduce from the central limit theorem that X and Y are normally distributed

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have zero mean. Let us consider the characteristic functions $f$ of $X$, $g$ of $Y$, $h$ of $X+Y$, $j$ of $X-Y$.

Now, $h(s)j(t)$ is the average of $e^{i(s+t)X+i(s-t)Y}$, thus $h(s)j(t)=f(s+t)g(s-t)$. In particular, $h(s)=f(s)g(s)$, $j(t)=f(t)g(-t)$.

Thus $f(s)f(t)g(s)g(-t)=f(s+t)g(s-t)$. (E)

Now write $s=u+v$, $t=u-v$, then $f(u+v)f(u+(-v))g(u-(-v))g(v-u)=f(2u)g(2v)$.

Applying (E) to the left-hand side yields: 
$f(2u)g(2v)=f(u)f(v)g(v)g(-u)f(u)f(-v)g(u)g(v)=f(u)^2g(v)^2|f(v)|^2|g(u)|^2$.

Thus $f(2u)=c_1f(u)^2|g(u)|^2$, $g(2v)=c_2|f(v)|^2g(v)^2$, for some constants $c_1,c_2$. Hence $c_1=c_2=1$ (with $u=v=0$).

In particular, $|f|=|g|$, and the set of zeroes of $fg$ is stable under division by $2$ and closed. Since it does not contain $0$, $|f|$ does not vanish.

In particular, there exists a unique differentiable function $\theta$ such that $f=ge^{i\theta}$, and $\theta(0)=0$.

The equations and uniqueness yield that $\theta(2t)=2\theta(t)$, which entails $\theta(t)=\theta’(0)t$. Now since $X$ and $Y$ have zero mean, $\theta’(0)=0$ hence $f=g$.

Edit: I realize I did not address the last part of the question. I am adding it now.

$X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent and integrable thus so is their product $X^2-Y^2$, thus, for some large $R>0$, so is $|X^2-Y^2|1(|Y| \leq R) \geq X^21(|Y| \leq R) -R^2$. Therefore, $X^21(|Y| \leq R)$ is $L^1$, hence, if $|Y| \leq R$ has positive probability, $X^2$ is integrable.

Comment: but why $X$ and $Y$ are integrable??

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ must be integrable, else you cannot write $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ in your question...

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ or $X+Y$ doesn't need to be integrable, in my question I asked first why $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are integrable, which is true under the above assumption (the independence), and then we can define $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ and we can use your method, that's why I am asking why $X$ and $Y$ are integrable